# How do I best identify a String that contains JSON in it?

Tags: java, json, regex, parsing

I want to know how I can identify a String that contains JSON inside it. I am writing some monitoring functionality, and I would like to be able to do something if a String contains a JSON.

Here is the thing, the Strings I am parsing would not be 100% JSON, it would have JSON content within it. Here is an example:

```
"bla bla bla {"key": "value"} bla bla bla"
```

With this I cannot do traditional techniques such as *try and parse it to JSON to see if it works*

I am fiddling with regex but I can't seem to find a good solution that doesn't seem *messy*.

I am ok with a reasonable margin of error, but are there any good ways to do this?

Just FYI: I am in a Java environment

**EDIT1**

Ok, to give you guys more context on what I want to do. Basically I need to monitor log statements that we are printing out. Based on previous events, we had some issues with logging of JSON payloads that should not be logged (especially above debug level).

I have other monitoring rules, but this is one that I would like to add. So it doesn't need to be 100% failsafe.

I removed the escaped quotes, they really made no sense.

Comment: This sounds like a fundamentally bad idea. Not everything that can be parsed as JSON would be intended to be JSON. For example, "The default value of every reference type is null, and the default value of the boolean type is false" contains two valid JSON documents. Are you sure you'd want to include that JSON? And why does your example have escaped `"` values? If you could give us some more context, we may be able to suggest a better approach.

Comment: Well technically only objects and array should be supported as top level JSON, so I suppose he could find { and [ and get the string till the matching closing { or ] (taking care of nesting)...

Comment: I agree with @JonSkeet, sounds like a bad idea. Perhaps if you want to do just a rudimentary check it will be good enough? something like `\{.*?\}`?

Comment: @JonSkeet I added more context on what I am trying to do, I hope this helps

Comment: @JonSkeet Not just a bad idea, it is also impossible using strictly regular expressions.  Though it's hardly his fault if he's having to clean up a mess.

Comment: @JPMoresmau: RFC 7159 makes no such constraints on the value of a JSON text, although it does note that previous versions did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matching precisely valid json is tricky because it could be potentially very large.  It'd be the same as parsing json using a regular expression.  Instead what you could do is check for *potential* JSON using a regular expression.  I assume you want to remove it or do something with it, so it is okay to overshoot and collect more than what is necessary.

You can use the following regular expression string `"(?:\\{\\\".+\\\"\\:.*\\}|\\[.*\\])"` to greedily match anything resembling json.

With the matches found, you can perform a formal json parse to verify that it is, in fact, json prior to removing it.

Comment: I went with your approach but being a little less greedy. I removed the or condition and worked well for me. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If it is going to have the form you gave, extracts all the possible `{somethingherebutIdon'tKnowwhat}` and then parse to see if they are json (matching opening with closing bracket).